# How to get applied coupon code amount in the order collection in magento2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order

I have applied a coupon code and placed an order.I need that coupon code amount that has been applied from the order collection.

Thanks in advance.

I got the coupon with this piece of line

```
$order->getCouponPrice()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the column(base_discount_amount) in the sales_order table

So I have used the below line to get the discount amount.

```
$order->getBaseDiscountAmount()
```